# How can I clear memcache using capistrano?

Tags: memcached, capistrano

I use capistrano to deploy my app to a machine that uses memcache.  I want capistrano to clear memcache when it deploys a new version of the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this GIST solves the problem: https://gist.github.com/matthuhiggins/668744

Comment: Link seems to lead to a spam.

Comment: Maybe the blog was ended. I'll get it on webarchive and post on gist or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

[Something like that?](http://github.com/engineyard/eycap/blob/35c69f12aa78b5ee6f99bd9c1b22980698076b1f/lib/eycap/recipes/memcached.rb)

Comment: I found that I couldn't start memcached using the Capistrano recipe you linked to.  Then I found this: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/83485.  That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know capistrano, but can't you just kill the memcached process and spawn a new one?
Better probably for removing fragmentation also.

Comment: capistrano is deployment automation tool, so that restart would also be done by capistrano.

Answer (score 0):

This, by Susan Potter looks pretty good https://gist.github.com/rays/154570

```
# 2007 Copyright Susan Potter <me at susanpotter dot net>
# You can read her software development rants at: http://geek.susanpotter.net
# Released under CreativeCommons-attribution-noncommercial-sharealike license:
# http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/1.0/
namespace :memcached do
  desc "Restart the Memcache daemon"
  task :restart, :roles => :app do
    deploy.memcached.stop
    deploy.memcached.start
  end

  desc "Start the Memcache daemon"
  task :start, :roles => :app do
    invoke_command "memcached -P #{current_path}/log/memcached.pid  -d", :via => run_method
  end

  desc "Stop the Memcache daemon"
  task :stop, :roles => :app do
    pid_file = "#{current_path}/log/memcached.pid"
    invoke_command("killall -9 memcached", :via => run_method) if File.exist?(pid_file)
  end
end
```